# External Interface in Flash Actionscript 2 working on one site, but not another

Tags: javascript, actionscript-2, flash, externalinterface

I am using externalinterface.addcallback to access Actionscript from an HTML page and pass a variable back.
This is the main code I am using

```
// Gives access to key functionality provided by an external Javascript interface
import flash.external.*;

function disableInput()
{
    barrier._visible = true;
}

// sends score back to Claroline
function getGrade()
{
    grade = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        if (_root["unsafeAct" + i].score != undefined)
        {
            grade += _root["unsafeAct" + i].score;
        }
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        if (_root["unsafeCon" + i].score != undefined)
        {
            grade += _root["unsafeCon" + i].score;
        }
    }
    trace(grade);
    return (grade);
}

// Changes external interface exposure as this seems to cause issues
System.security.allowDomain("*");

// Maps the flash object API calls to the current SWF's equivalent function
ExternalInterface.addCallback("CheckAnswers",this,checkAnswers);
ExternalInterface.addCallback("GetGrade",this,getGrade);
ExternalInterface.addCallback("SerializeAnswers",this,serializeAnswers);
ExternalInterface.addCallback("DeserializeAnswers",this,deserializeAnswers);
ExternalInterface.addCallback("EnableInput",this,enableInput);
ExternalInterface.addCallback("DisableInput",this,disableInput);
```

I have no access to the HTML and Javascript as they are generated by the Claroline LMS.  I am publishing for Flash Player 9 and Actionscript 2.

The externalinterface code was taken from a working exercise, and works fine inside Dreamweaver, but fails to work inside Claroline.

I'm presuming that there is some sort of security issue, possibly with newer versions of the flash player, but I can't find any information about it.

If anyone has any ideas about this, it'd be fantastic.

Many thanks

Charlie

Answer (score -1):

I recently ran into a similar issue. I had a call on the timeline to `ExternalInterface` that would never trigger. What solved it for me was to nest the `ExternalInterface` call within another function and then call that function instead:

Does NOT work:

```
ExternalInterface.call("unlockPage","");
```

Does work:

```
function unlockPage(){
    ExternalInterface.call("unlockPage","");
}

unlockPage();
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Wow this question was really old :)